# "Could not convert string to float:''

Tags: python, tkinter, type-conversion

I am a very beginner in terms of coding. I am trying to calculate the sum of the order but python keeps telling me that it could not convert the string to float. Could you please show me where the error lies?

```
import tkinter as tk

window = tk.Tk()

window.title("Cinema")
window.geometry("700x600")

def total_():
    a= float(e1.get())*2
    b= float(e2.get())*3
    c= float(e3.get())*4
    d= float(e5.get())*1
    e= float(e4.get())*12
    totl = a+b+c+d+e
    tax= (totl * 0.13 + 0.13)
    lblAns['text'] = "Your total is {}$".format(totl)

#Cinema name
Cine_nom = tk.Label(window)
Cine_nom['text'] = "Welcome to cinema !"
Cine_nom['font'] = "Arial 20 bold"
Cine_nom.place(x=350, y=20, anchor="center")

# Menu Creation
label1 = tk.Label(window,
text="Menu",
font="times 28 bold")

label1.place(x=520, y=70)

label2 = tk.Label(window, text="Popcorn (P) \
2$", font="times 18")

label2.place(x=450, y=120)

label3 = tk.Label(window, text="Popcorn (M) \
3$", font="times 18")

label3.place(x=450, y=150)

label4 = tk.Label(window, text="Popcorn (L) \
4$", font="times 18")
label4.place(x=450, y=180)

label5 = tk.Label(window, text="Burger Combo \
12$", font="times 18")

label5.place(x=450, y=210)

label6 = tk.Label(window, text="Soda \
1$", font="times 18")

label6.place(x=450, y=240)

# Entry Table
label9 = tk.Label(window, text="Select the items",
font="times 18")
label9.place(x=115, y=70)

label10 = tk.Label(window,
text="Popcorn (P)",
font="times 18")
label10.place(x=20, y=120)

e1 = tk.Entry(window)
e1.place(x=20, y=150)

label11 = tk.Label(window, text="Popcorn (M)",
font="times 18")
label11.place(x=20, y=200)

e2= tk.Entry(window)
e2.place(x=20, y=230)

label12 = tk.Label(window, text="Popcorn (L)",
font="times 18")
label12.place(x=20, y=280)

e3= tk.Entry(window)
e3.place(x=20, y=310)

label13 = tk.Label(window,
text="Burger Combo",
font="times 18")
label13.place(x=20, y=360)

e4 = tk.Entry(window)
e4.place(x=20, y=390)

label14 = tk.Label(window,
text="Soda",
font="times 18")
label14.place(x=20, y=420)
e5 = tk.Entry(window)
e5.place(x=20, y=450)

# Button for total
btnCalculate = tk.Button(window)
btnCalculate['text'] = "Calculate your bill"
btnCalculate['font'] = "Arial 15"
btnCalculate['command'] = total_
btnCalculate.place(x=30, y=480)

lblAns = tk.Label(window)
lblAns['text'] = ""
lblAns.place(x=40, y=700)

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: What are `e1, ..., e5`? I assume the get method for those is returning a string that cannot be converted to float. It should tell you what is trying to be converted in the error message too. Something like `ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'hello'` if attempting to convert the string hello to float.

Comment: Hi, I added my whole code so that it's easier to understand. As for the type of error, it's saying: ValueError: could not convert string to float: ''.

Comment: The error message is telling you it cannot convert the empty string to float. Do the Entry components have values typed into them?

Comment: Normally, it should multiply the string by whatever the user types in. If you compile my code, you can see that you can input the amount of item you want.

Comment: Please see my answer below. It shows how to set defaults for your entry boxes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works for me when I add input to the entry boxes. I think you just need to move the statement being displayed. I changed

```
lblAns.place(x=40, y=700)
```

to

```
lblAns.place(x=40, y=550)
```

I then typed 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 into the five entry boxes (top to bottom). It printed `Your total is 73.0$`. Given that these are quantities, I think `int` is a better choice than `float`.

To set a default value try something like below for each Entry.

```
e1.insert(0, 0)
```

Something like below will also work.

```
def total_():
    a= float(e1.get() or 0)*2
    b= float(e2.get() or 0)*3
    c= float(e3.get() or 0)*4
    d= float(e5.get() or 0)*1
    e= float(e4.get() or 0)*12
    totl = a+b+c+d+e
    tax= (totl * 0.13 + 0.13)
    lblAns['text'] = "Your total is {}$".format(totl)
```

Comment: Hello, it works when the user chooses the quantity on every option but when choosing only one of the items, the code crashes. I also changed the float to an int but still ends with : ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

Comment: See my update and use something like `e1.insert(0, 0)` for each Entry. Or the other approach shown.

Comment: May god bless you! Thank you very much for all the help. Your answer worked a wonder! Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

```
# use a debugger or print(type(variable)) to check types
def total_():
    a = float(e1.get() * 2)
    b = float(e2.get() * 3)
    c = float(e3.get() * 4)
    d = float(e5.get() * 1)
    e = float(e4.get() * 12)
    totl = float(a + b + c + d + e)
    tax = float((totl * 0.13) + 0.13)
    lblAns['text'] = f"Your total is {totl}"
```

Comment: Hello, I tried it again with your suggestion but it still could not convert the string to a float. Thank you tho!